# REST - Correct error code for country (Geo Location) restricted resource

Tags: web-services, rest, http

What is the correct http error code for geographical restriction?

Meaning, the service has a resource that is limited for access only from several countries. The service needs to fail all requests not from the closed list of approved countries.

Should I use 403?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would also use `403`. You may additionally change the status string to say it is "Geo restricted", or something.

If you want it to be automatically consumable, you may also define a special error format (`media-type`) that would contain some details about the issue.